# ASP.NET Output Caching not working after upgrade from MVC2 to MVC4

Tags: caching, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

We have an existing MVC2 project that we just upgraded to MVC4 following first [these steps](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading) to get to MVC3, then [these steps](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806) to get to MVC4.

Output caching had been successfully working for a long time in our MVC2 project, but it does not work after the MVC4 version.

I've added a simple controller to test caching:

```
 public class TestController : Controller
 {
    [OutputCache(Duration = 600, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public ActionResult CacheTest()
    {
        return Content(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    }
 }
```

Each time i refresh this page, the time output to the browser changes.

Creating a new MVC3 project in this same solution, then upgrading to MVC4, then copying this same code over works as expected.

So there must be something somewhere in our existing code or configuration that is breaking output caching.

I've also tried stripping out a ton of stuff from the web.config file thinking something there was causing problems - no luck.

Any suggestions on how to fix or debug this?

**UPDATE:**

Rendering the CacheTest action above in any view will display cached results - i.e. the date does not change on each refresh:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("CacheTest", "Test"); %>
```

Why does that work, but the action url from a browser is never cached?

Comment: Are you using the same webserver? Did you change from Cassini to IIS Express?

Comment: Yes no change here.  I've also verified the same undesirable results on IIS 7.5 on win2008 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with a third party library - [51Degrees](http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Forum/tabid/65/forumid/2/threadid/1974/scope/posts/Default.aspx).   This was an issue introduced into a recent version of this library.  In the process of converting from MVC2 to MVC4 I installed the nuget package which was a few versions later than the previous version I was using.

False alarm - nothing to do with the ASP.NET MVC upgrade or anything ASP.NET related.